# Athena bigint and double on the same column having error

Tags: amazon-web-services, types, casting, type-conversion, amazon-athena

Athena has a column which has both type of value bigint (1)
and double(2.10000000000000009) . when I am doing select * from the that table . I am facing error
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field windSpeed's type DOUBLE in parquet is incompatible with type bigint defined in table schema.

Comment: were you able to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The error says the Parquet column is of type DOUBLE, use that type for the table column too.

Comment: When i am making it DOUBLE it is asking to change it to INT64 because it contain integers too

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to make that part clear?

Comment: i have a column which has both type of values , bigint and double . While creating the table on top this dataset , for this particular column when i am giving double it is expecting bigint and when i am providing bigint then it is expecting it to be double

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Following this if it ever gets answered! I know ideally the column data should have only one data type but in my use case there is some old data with one data type and some new with another.

Comment: Use string, that should work for both cases. But in general, it's a bad idea to change the data type of a column between files, you shouldn't expect that to work flawlessly. The files are not compatible.